# django CSRF validation

Tags: django, csrf, django-csrf

I can't get around the CSRF token validation 403 error.
Here's what I have:

view:

```
from django.template import RequestContext
def add(request, name):
#logic
return render_to_response("category/add.html", {"form": form}, 
    context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

template:

```
<form action="/category/add/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    New Category: <input type="text" name="name" id="categoryname" />
    <input type="submit" value="Hinzufuegen" />
</form>
```

settings:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you need to add

```
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfResponseMiddleware',
```

to your MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES. Seems that it is not validating CSRF token, just generating...
helped me in [my case](http://garmoncheg.blogspot.com/2011/07/django-upgrading-django-from-11-to-125.html)...

Comment: Use of the CsrfResponseMiddleware is not recommended because of the performance hit it imposes, and because of a potential security problem (see below). It can be used as an interim measure until applications have been updated to use the csrf_token tag. It is deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.4. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/csrf/#legacy-method

Answer (score 2):

Are you passing the POST data to the form for validation? You have to do something like this:

```
     from django.template import RequestContext
     def add(request, name):
       # Logic
       if request.type == "POST":
         form = YourFormClass(request.POST)
         if form.is_valid():
             # Success!
         else:
             # Invalid form
       else:
         return render_to_response("category/add.html", {"form": form}, 
         context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```